# In Star Wars lore, who made the first light saber and how was it developed?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Extended universe books allude to a Jedi having to "forge" their own light saber as part of their trials. It seems to be both a rite of passage, and a somewhat holy experience. The connection isn't really explored more than that, though.

How did this forging process become part of Jedi tradition?

Is there a similar tradition for the Sith?

Who made the first light saber, and how was the process developed from one of engineering a weapon to the holy trial for the warrior sect?

Are there any more powerful light sabers within canon?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/First_Blade